# javascript getting undefined after find object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, find

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have a simple code:

```
console.log(req.params.id); 
let tour = tournaments.find((item) => {return item.id === req.params.id});
console.log(tournaments);
console.log(tour);
console.log(req.params.id);
```

Where `tournaments` is an array of objects. Here is my output:

```
1592563085412
[
  Tournament {
    id: 1592563085412,
    discipline: 'chess',
    type: 'Bracket Tournament',
    description: 'des 1',
    date: '2020-06-19 12:38:05'
  }
]
undefined
1592563085412
```

Why I am getting undefined after `console.log(tour);` What should I change? I expected to receive an object where `id = 1592563085412`

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: could it be `typeof req.params.id === string`?

Comment: you can also do implicit return `let tour = tournaments.find((item) => item.id === req.params.id);` no need for return keyword

Comment: with all the information that you've provided your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/pfz0jxou/ Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that both `item.id` and `req.params.id` are of the same type. For that u can add the logging:

```
console.log(typeof item.id)
console.log(typeof req.params.id)
```

If they are not of the same type, use `==` or better convert both to the same type. E.g. `parseInt(req.params.id, 10)`. I expect `req.params.id` to be the culprit since request params are serialized to string.

See this Post: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494)

> The strict equality operator (===) behaves identically to the abstract
>   equality operator (==) except no type conversion is done, and the
>   types must be the same to be considered equal.

Comment: Yes, I solved this 15 seconds ago ;D Anyway thanks! :)